# python Beautifulsoup how to get text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a issue to get the text from this, i cannot do `.text` at the end of `find_all()`.

I would like to get the text into `('a', class_ = 'tw-hidden lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between')`

I'm beginner, i've tried many things but i get stocked, if someone can help me, that would be nice.

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for i in range(2):

    url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/fr?page=1' + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        coin = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tw-hidden lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between')
    print(coin)
```

Comment: You are not indenting correctly after `for` block

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

`find_all()` create a results set / a list, that do not have a method `.text`.

#### How to get the text?

Simply iterate over your result set and call the `.text` methode on each element separatly:

```
for coin in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tw-hidden lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between'):
    print(coin.text)
```

#### Hint

You can use `get_text(strip=True)` to get a "cleaner" result:

```
for coin in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tw-hidden lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between'):    
    print(coin.get_text(strip=True))
```

#### Complete example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for i in range(2):

    url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/fr?page=1' + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        for coin in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tw-hidden lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between'):
            print(coin.get_text(strip=True))
```

#### Output

```
Neblio
Measurable Data Token
Secret Finance
MASS
88mph
GROWTH DeFi
My DeFi Pet
Bridge Mutual
Dfyn Network
e-Money
Defi Warrior
DeepBrain Chain
Peony Coin
Oraichain Token
FOAM
DVF
...
```